# Entity Framework Core not making nullable int? (foreign key) as nullable column until I explicitly mark the referring object as nullable

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core and I am facing a strange issue which never occurred before. I am using PostgreSQL provider.

The issue is I am creating a foreign key column as nullable like this

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(TeamLead))]
public int? TeamLeadId { get; set; }

public User TeamLead { get; set; }
```

but the in the generated query it is used as not nullable.

After trying many solutions, when I make `User` explicitly nullable, it works. But it's strange because objects are by default nullable.

Like this:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(TeamLead))]
public int? TeamLeadId { get; set; }

public User? TeamLead { get; set; }
```

What could be the issue - any suggestions?

Comment: *"because objects are by default nullable"* - not true when the NRT is enabled at project level, which is now the default for net6+ projects. Unfortunately MS is pushing all their teams (thus EF Core) to use/utilize NRT, w/o  carrying about breaking changes like this. My suggestion is to always put `#nullable disable` at the top of the code files containing entity model classes.